# 403 Forbidden error using cron and curl

Tags: php, curl, cron

I have an fcron job to run a php script in the background and the output is written into a file. However the only outout I get is a 403 forbiden error. My fcron is working but it does not have access to my localhost. How can I make sure that fcron job has access to localhost? I am the owner of localhost i.e the folder where my localhost is(I know it isnt safe but this is production purposes).entry in fcrontab:

```
0 * * * * curl "http://localhost/main/sendmail.php"
```

Comment: Does your fcron has access to remote domain ? within your local area network (http://anotherhost) or outside (http://www.google.fr) ?

Comment: Does both fcron and page are hosted on the same host ?

Comment: Does the curl command works properly outside of the cron ?

Comment: @snowflake yes curl command works in command line. It is hosted in the same domain localhost. When I put a common url e.g www.google.com it works okay. I need to run crontab as admin or as someone who has access to localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. Create the fcrontab as super user aka su. SU has permission to everything.